# Animations Bar can't be found in Construct 2

Tags: windows-10, construct-2

I'm trying to do animations on Windows 10, but I can't find the animations bar. Is there a hotkey to bring up the Animations Bar?

Answer (score 1):

Old bump. but still...
Maybe you should try to reset the dialogs.

File **>>** Preferences **>>** [Reset dialogs]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Construct 2 pops up Windows in odd locations.  If, for instance, you are using multiple monitors, the Animations Bar might have popped up on the other monitor, and maybe behind other applications.  Not really sure why this happens, but I've certainly had to do some digging before.  All in all, close all your other Windows and look around on other monitors.  It should be there by default, just might be hidden :)